# How to connect MySQL using Heidi SQL in Scotch Box?

Tags: mysql, vagrant

I am trying to connect mysql using heidi sql in my scotch-box (Vagrant), but i am getting errors while connecting.

> Error : Cant connect to MySQLserver on localhost (1006)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: try this]

[image: Try this also]

Please try with this settings.

Comment: This configuration working in my laptop, but i am facing the above issue in my desktop